# Select muestra Background en blanco de sus opciones seleccionadas

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un `Select` el cual contiene 3 colores como opciones, pero cuando selecciono una opción esta no muestra el color de fondo, solo muestra el texto:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Puntos...</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .rojo {background-color:#FF0000;}
            .azul {background-color:#0066FF;}
            .verde {background-color:#009900;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="" method="">
            <select name="opciones">
                <option class="rojo">Rojo</option>
                <option class="azul">azul</option>
                <option class="verde">Verde</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: quieres mostrarlo en el body?

Comment: Pero en ningún momento le estas cambiando el `Background` al `Body`.

Comment: asi es eso se hace con jquery

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez no quiero cambiar el color del body, lo que pasa es que en el select cuando selecciono por ejemplo el color verde cambia el background  de la opcion que elegi a color blanco y no se queda en verde

Answer (score 6):

para esto es necesario utilizar javascript y manejar el evento `onchange` para cambiar el background del select dependiendo la opción seleccionada

agrega el siguiente código luego de la etiqueta de cierre `</style>`

```
<script>
    var e = document.getElementsByName("opciones")[0];

    e.className = e.options[e.selectedIndex].className;

    e.onchange = function(){
      e.className = e.options[e.selectedIndex].className;
    }
</script>
```

[mira el codigo funcionando](https://jsfiddle.net/1a1d57w3/9/)

### Edit

En caso de querer utilizar el `atributo style` en vez de clases css
deberías acceder a cada propiedad css en el style y modificar su valor

```
    var e = document.getElementsByName("opciones")[0];

    e.style.backgroundColor = e.options[e.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor;

    e.onchange = function(){
      e.style.backgroundColor = e.options[e.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor;
    }
```

[mira el código funcionando para esta actualización](https://jsfiddle.net/1a1d57w3/16/)

Comment: funcionaria igual si incorporo directamente el estilo a la opcion por ejemplo <option style="background-color:Red">Rojo</option>?

Comment: no funcionaria. className toma la clase (no el atributo style) que definiste en cada elemento.

Comment: y como puedo hacerlo de esta forma <option style="background-color:Red">Rojo</option>

Comment: como buena practica, te recomiendo utilizar las clases. el problema de los style en este caso es que debes seleccionar cada una de las propiedades que usas. por ejemplo si usas background-color, margin y padding entonces tienes que asignar cada propiedad en el select lo cual triplicarias el codigo. si lo necesitas, adapto la respuesta para los dos casos.

Comment: actualice mi respuesta, mi elección es utilizar nombre de clases. saludos

Comment: me aparece Cannot read property 'style' of undefined(   e.style.backgroundColor)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74578/discussion-between-mauro-petrini-and-ivxn).

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo haría con JQuery de esta manera. Espero te sirva.

```js
var select = $("select"); // Select
// Estado inicial del Select. Agregar clase de la opción seleccionada.
select.attr("class", select.children(":selected").attr("class"));

// Al cambiar
select.change(function() {
   var selected = $(this).children(":selected").attr("class");
   $(this).attr("class", selected);
});
```

```css
.rojo {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.azul {
  background-color: #0066FF;
}

.verde {
  background-color: #009900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="opciones" id="myselect">
    <option class="rojo">Rojo</option>
    <option class="azul">azul</option>
    <option class="verde">Verde</option>
</select>
```